# How to restart a failed amdgpu kernel module

Tags: kernel-modules, video, graphics, amd-graphics, proprietary-drivers

My video card crashes from time to time. It's quite annoying but I live with it -- usually I just restart the graphics with `sudo systemctl restart lightdm.service`, or if needed reboot the whole system.

In this particular instance the `systemctl` call hangs, and I **don't want to reboot** since I have a long-running job on the machine.

The crash is logged in `dmesg` as

```
[944520.212254] Call Trace:
[944520.212256]  [<ffffffff818384d5>] schedule+0x35/0x80
[944520.212257]  [<ffffffff8183b625>] schedule_timeout+0x1b5/0x270
[944520.212280]  [<ffffffffc0235244>] ? dce_v6_0_program_watermarks+0x514/0x720 [amdgpu]
[944520.212282]  [<ffffffffc0196d2c>] kcl_fence_default_wait+0x1cc/0x260 [amdkcl]
[944520.212287]  [<ffffffff815b4f50>] ? fence_free+0x20/0x20
```

Clearly the `amdgpu` module crashed. I would like to restart it, so I tried

```
sudo modprobe -r amdgpu
modprobe: FATAL: Module amdgpu is in use.
```

And when I try to find out who is using `amdgpu` I get

```
lsmod | grep amdgpu
amdgpu               2129920  7
amdttm                102400  1 amdgpu
amdkcl                 32768  1 amdgpu
i2c_algo_bit           16384  1 amdgpu
drm_kms_helper        155648  1 amdgpu
drm                   364544  10 drm_kms_helper,amdgpu,amdkcl,amdttm
```

Basically there is 7 "things" using the module and I have no idea how to find them and remove the `amdgpu` module.

**Question**: Is there any reasonable way to reload the module, without rebooting the system? Or is there a better way to get my video back?

Comment: @ChrisStryczynski nope, i got an nvidia card

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As @Chris Stryczynski says, `sudo cat /sys/kernel/debug/dri/N/amdgpu_gpu_recover` is the correct way to reload the amdgpu kernel module, or you can start your system with `amdgpu.gpu_recovery=1` kernel parameter to automatically reset it on a crash.

But these options are not usable so much because the display server ( Xorg or Wayland ) has to reinitialize its graphic stack and desktop environments are not capable of doing that. (Not yet implemented.)

Using the gpu_recovery kernel parameter, you can save your work even if it's not visible, and then reboot.

Answer (score 3):

https://github.com/RadeonOpenCompute/ROCK-Kernel-Driver/issues/11#issuecomment-450696825

> If you do not want to have these resets attempted automatically, or if
>   your lockup is not being detected, you should be able to use the
>   debugfs mechanism to perform a manual GPU reset, even if you have not
>   set the gpu_recovery parameter. To do this, (as root) read
>   /sys/kernel/debug/dri/N/amdgpu_gpu_recover. N in this case is the
>   number of the GPU you wish to reset in the DRI subsystem.

---

This never worked for me... But thought I'd post it none the less.